# "If-Match or If-None-Match header or entry etag attribute required" Error when trying to update a contact on google contacts using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-contacts-api

Hi guys I'm trying to update my google contacts using the zend framework but I'm getting the following error:

```
Expected response code 200, got 403 If-Match or If-None-Match header or entry etag attribute required
```

The following is my code:

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Feed');

$client = getGoogleClient('cp'); // this is a function I made - its working fine
$client->setHeaders('If-Match: *');

$gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
$gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query($id);// id is the google reference 

$entry = $gdata->getEntry($query);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($entry->getXML());

$xml->name->fullName = trim($contact->first_name).' '.trim($contact->last_name);

$entryResult = $gdata->updateEntry($xml->saveXML(), $id);
```

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

i got a solution in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14476692

here is the message from that link:

> // in listing 6... // somewhere before
>   the updateEntry call add:
>   $extra_header = array();
>   $extra_header='*';
>
> // and then replace the current
>   updateEntry call with the following:
>   $entryResult =
>   $gdata->updateEntry($xml->saveXML(),$entry->getEditLink()->href,null,$extra_header);
>
> Updates to Google Contacts now work.

i get it work for my code. again there is a problem with the code in the post as well.
that is

```
$extra_header = array(); 

$extra_header = array('If-Match'=>'*'); 

$entryResult  = $contactObj->updateEntry($xml->saveXML(),$entry->getEditLink()->href,null,$extra_header);
```

I think it will help you solve the update problem as well.

thanks